# How to add php repositories to debian kali linux for php files?

Tags: php, linux, terminal, zsh, kali-linux

I have added

packages.sury.org/php

through the script, I got on deb.sury.org

===========================================

```
#!/bin/sh
# To add this repository please do:

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    SUDO=sudo
fi

${SUDO} apt-get update
${SUDO} apt-get -y install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates curl
${SUDO} curl -sSLo /usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
${SUDO} sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg] https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
${SUDO} apt-get update
```

===========================================

After running the script is gives an error:

```
Ign:5 https://packages.sury.org/php kali-rolling InRelease

Err:6 https://packages.sury.org/php kali-rolling Release

404  Not Found [IP: 102.129.144.44 443]
```

and then continues.
I can't even add the ubuntu repo it gives the same result and I think that one is one is worse.

I also add [trusted=yes] to the php.list file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory

It gives an even longer error.
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run as root:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

rm -f /usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg
rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list

apt-get update
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl
curl -sSLo /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/sury-php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ bullseye main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sury-php.list
apt-get update
```

Officially, the `https://packages.sury.org/php/` repo directory only supports the following distribution names: `bullseye`, `buster` and `stretch`. And you have Kali Linux. I replaced the Kali Linux release name with the Debian release name.

Comment: Appreciate so much